# How to make AvalonDock's floating child window dock when user double-clicks its title bar?

Tags: c#, docking, avalondock

I am relatively new for [AvalonDock 2.0](http://avalondock.codeplex.com/documentation) but I heard that one can change the behavior of title bar double-clicked in a floating child window with this new version. But I can't find any clue over Google or its own site. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying source of AvalonDock because it's just addition of 6 lines. If you know any better way, please post your answer.

In `switch` statement of `FilterMessage` method of `LayoutAnchorableFloatingWindowControl.cs`

```
            case Win32Helper.WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK:
                _model.Descendents().OfType<LayoutAnchorablePane>().First(p => p.ChildrenCount > 0 && p.SelectedContent != null).SelectedContent.Dock();
                break;
```

In `switch` statement of `FilterMessage` method of `LayoutDocumentFloatingWindowControl.cs`

```
            case Win32Helper.WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK:
                _model.RootDocument.Dock();
                break;
```